# tee sends incomplete data

Tags: linux, tee

```
$ head -c10G /dev/zero |
  tee >(head -c1M | wc -c) >(head -c10M | wc -c) >(head -c100M | wc -c) >(head -c1000M | wc -c)
```

gives:

```
1048576
1064960
1064960
1064960
```

I would have expected:

```
1048576
10485760
104857600
1048576000
```

I imagine it is due to `head -c1M` closing the pipe and `tee` then only writes one block more to the other processes, before it discovers that it cannot write to the first process and then exits.

Can I ask `tee` to skip the closed receiver, but keep on writing to the others?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `tee --output-error=exit-nopipe`. That would ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal and the `EPIPE` write error, but will still die on any other errors.

`tee --output-error=exit-nopipe`, just like the `warn` variant from your answer, does exit when it cannot write to at least one of its outputs; but it does count the standard output as one of them.

Your examples are buggy because they just dump the output of `head -c10G /dev/zero | tee ...` to your terminal (which you cannot see because the null byte is "invisible"); and that's why the `tee` in your answer doesn't exit: because it will be still writing to stdout after the `>(...)` process substitutions have exited.

For systems without GNU tee, a possible workaround is to append a `cat >/dev/null` to the commands the output of `tee` is piped to; but you cannot do that with all of them; you'll have to decide on a "master" output which will cause `tee` to exit if writing to it doesn't succeed. Example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero |
  tee >(dd of=/dev/null count=200; cat >/dev/null) >(dd of=/dev/null count=700; cat >/dev/null) |
  dd of=/dev/null count=1000
$ dd if=/dev/zero |
  tee >(dd of=/dev/null count=1000) >(dd of=/dev/null count=700; cat >/dev/null) |
  { dd of=/dev/null count=200; cat >/dev/null; }
```

Both should write 200, 700 and 1000 blocks respectively.

Comment: Try `tee -p`, example: `head -c5M /dev/zero |   tee -p >(dd count=4000) >(dd count=700)`

Comment: @Isaac `tee -p` will continue happily running even after an EIO or ENOSPC error when writing to a regular file; you usually don't want that, so `--output-error=exit-nopipe` is better.

Comment: Can anyone hazard a guess as to why `exit-nopipe` is not default.. ? (Note: `pee` from moreutils ignores SIGPIPE)

Answer (score 0):

It seems `--output-error=warn` does this.

```
head -c10G /dev/zero |
  tee --output-error=warn >(head -c10M | wc -c) >(head -c100M | wc -c) >(head -c1000M | wc -c)
```

Unfortunately it also spams warnings on stderr and it does not exit if it cannot write to any of them.

Comment: `tee --output-error=warn` will exit if it cannot write to any of its outputs -- it just counts the stdout as one of them. Use `warn-nopipe` instead of `warn` if you want to suppress the spurious errors. Another possible workaround for systems without GNU tee is to add a `cat >/dev/null` after the commands in the process substitutions: eg `>(head ...; cat >/dev/null)`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that any pipe that blocks will send a SIGPIPE to `tee` and stop it:

```
$ head -c10G /dev/zero |   tee >(head -c10 | wc -c) >(head -c1M | wc -c)
10
65536
```

The command `tee` is receiving the SIGPIPE from the first pipe and causing all the childs to exit.

You would need to expand each pipe to have no limit:

```
$ head -c10G /dev/zero |   tee >({ head -c10 | wc -c; }; cat >/dev/null )  >(head -c1M | wc -c)
10
1048576
```

for all the cases you have given:

```
$ head -c10G /dev/zero |   tee >({ head -c1M | wc -c;}; cat >/dev/null) >({ head -c10M | wc -c; }; cat >/dev/null) >( { head -c100M | wc -c; }; cat>/dev/null) >(head -c1000M | wc -c)
1048576
10485760
104857600
1048576000
```

But it is simpler to tell `tee` to avoid exiting on pipe errors with the `-p` option:

```
$ head -c10M /dev/zero |   tee -p >(head -c10 | wc -c) >(head -c100 | wc -c) >(head -c1000| wc -c) >(head -c1M | wc -c)
100
1000
10
1048576
```

Which might print out of order.